# Pyhdbcli SAP HANA Connection DLL Load Fail

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, hana

Long time lurker hoping to get some assistance with connecting Python to SAP HANA.

I previously had it working perfectly however I recently wiped my Anaconda install to get a clean slate (start up performance issues with Jupyter) and now I can't get it to work at all!

When I try and run the connection via sqlalchemy I get the following traceback:

```
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\hdbcli\dbapi.py in <module>()

10 import sys

11

---> 12 import pyhdbcli

13 from .resultrow import ResultRow

14 

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

---

I have tried to follow the tutorial below (copy the 5 files into the python Lib folder)...
http://www.saphanacentral.com/p/power-of-python-integrated-with-sap-hana.html

However I don't seem to even have a Python folder under `C:\Program Files\sap\hdbclient` as they have suggested in the tutorial.

Therefore I assumed that I should put it in with the rest of my Python packages under `C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib`

So far without any success.

I would really appreciate any suggestions!
Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you need to download and install the SAP HANA client software first.

Comment: That could possibly be it. I definitely installed it in the past. Unless it somehow got removed when I uninstalled Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the HANA 2 SPS 2 client, you can install the client files using `pip` instead of copying the files over manually. This method is required if you are using Python 3.x.

Install the HANA Client using `./hdbinst`. You will be prompted for a install location. Once this installation is complete, locate the `hdbcli-2.x.x.tar.gz` file in the installation directory. From the Anaconda python environment prompt, run `pip install /path/to/hdbcli-2.x.x.tar.gz`.

You should then be able to access the dbapi module by running: 
`from hdbcli import dbapi`